# Delaying the execution of a function until string value is returned from javafx window

Tags: java, javafx

In my program the user the user enters a password on an external window, and then that password is passed through a function. The problem is that the function is executed before the user can enter a password. Here is my password window. Passw has already been declared as a static string for the class

```
public static String enterPassword()
{

    Stage primaryStage = new Stage();

    VBox vb = new VBox();

    vb.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));

    vb.setSpacing(10);

    HBox hb = new HBox();

    hb.setSpacing(10);

    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    Label label = new Label("Password");

    final PasswordField pb = new PasswordField();

    final TextField textField = new TextField();

    textField.setManaged(false);

    textField.setVisible(false);

    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Show/Hide password");

    textField.managedProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());


    textField.visibleProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());


    pb.managedProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());

    pb.visibleProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());

    // Bind the textField and passwordField text values 
    bidirectionally.

    textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(pb.textProperty());

    pb.setOnAction(e -> 
    {

        passw = pb.getText();




       pb.clear();
       primaryStage.hide();

    });

    textField.setOnAction(e -> 
    {

        passw = textField.getText();

        textField.clear();

        primaryStage.hide();
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(label, pb, textField, checkBox);
    vb.getChildren().addAll(hb);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 450, 90);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);


    primaryStage.show();



    return passw;

}
```

And here is the code in main where the function hostRun is executed

```
password = enterPassword();

while(password == null)
{

}

hostRun(4000000, '0', index, password, 0);
```

Here I try a while loop to delay the execution of hostRun but even that causes the password window to crash. How do I delay the execution of hostRun until the user enters a password?

Comment: unrelated: whatever you want to achieve, using static methods/fields is the wrong approach  (99.9999 %)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pause your program until the stage closed you can do that with:

```
primaryStage.showAndWait();
```

This will pause the method that invoked the stage until it closes.  No need for a loop.  Then enterPassword() will wait until the stage closes.

Comment: If you look at the code this isn't the primary stage of the app. It was just the variable name of the stage which your are instantiating with the keyword new. If this worked can you please mark accepted.